# Error when connecting to Exchange on other domain

Tags: c#, exchange-server, outlook-redemption

After connecting to Exchange on a different domain using:

```
rdoSession = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
rdoSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(Settings.Default.ExchangeServer, Settings.Default.ExchangeUserName, Settings.Default.ExchangePassword);
```

I want to get the default inbox folder:

`RDOFolder folder = rdoSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);`

But I get this error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040111): Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED
Make sure your code runs under the Windows user identity that has MAPI profiles.
When running in a service (including ASP under IIS), set your code to run under the Windows user account that has MAPI profiles.
When connecting to an Exchange Server, you can also use RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox which does not require an existing profile.
ulVersion: 0
Error: The information store could not be opened.
Component: MAPI 1.0
ulLowLevelError: 0
ulContext: 646
```

How can i read mails from exchange on different domain?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen for all mailboxes? Or just one?

Answer (score 0):

Sarah,

Consider using EWS instead. You can use Exchange Web Services (EWS) and other web services in Exchange Online, Exchange Online as part of Office 365, or Exchange on-premises to create solutions that enable your users to access Exchange mailbox data from services, websites, desktop computers, and mobile devices. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.